# Writing a default Comparator class in Java

Tags: java, oop, comparator, comparable

I am implementing a generic heap class in Java. There are two constructors for this class, one is the default constructor with no parameters. The other one takes in a comparator object that the user can pass in so that the user can control how the elements of a heap are compared. Now if the user uses the default constructor, I want my class to use to default comparator object. The compare method of this object simply calls the compareTo() method (part of the Comparable interface). Is there a way to do this and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess a generic comparator would look like that:

```
public class ComparableComparator<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparator<T> {
  @Override
  public int compare(T lhs, T rhs) {
    return lhs.compareTo(rhs);
  }  
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be Comparable<T>?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ComparableComparator`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/comparators/ComparableComparator.html) from Apache Commons that takes arbitrary two `Object`s and compares them if they implement `Comparable`.

Alternatively the constructor that does not take comparator should enforce `K extends Comparable<K>` type parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Guava provides the "natural ordering" `Comparator` as -- predictably enough -- [`Ordering.natural()`.](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#natural--)

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 has `Comparator.naturalOrder()` which you can use as default comparator. See [java.util.Comparator API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--) for details.